# g select: how do I pull value from one list and displayed options from another?

Tags: java, sql, grails, select, gsp

Say I have a database called `carNames`. I want the dropdown list to display the full names of each car, while I want the values of each of these to display only the ID of each car. It keeps making both the value and the displayed name the same thing no matter what I do, and based on all the changes I have done, it seems like only the `from` tag has any effect on the dropdown and it's values. Here is the code:

```
<g:select name="carDropdown" 
  from="${carNames.carOfficialName}"
  value="${carNames*.carId}"
  optionValue="${carNames*.carId[]}"
  optionKey="${carNames*.carId[]}"
  multiple="true" />
```

Comment: The from should be an object containing a list the key is a text value of list element as in id the value what you want to see as is name of name. That looks all wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the combined list in the serverside.

```
def cars = Car.findAll()
def carnames = magicCodeToGetCarNames()
def carnamemap = [:]
def cars_with_names = []
carnames.each {
 carnamemap[it.car_id] = it.carname
}
cars.each{
    cars_with_names << [
         id: it.id,
         carname: carnamemap[it.id],
         color: it.color,
         another: it.another,

    ]
}
```

Then pass `cars_with_names` to gsp page and use it to populate the dropdown.